# Why is my SSIS configuration update not being saved?

Tags: configuration, ssis, scheduled-tasks

I have a SSIS 2005 package that is up and running in our production environment. The package uses an SMTP Connection Manager to send an e-mail message out to a designated user. We have a scheduled job that executes this package, and also overrides the SMTP connection string so that the package can target the test or production mail server, which makes it possible to keep a single service on both our test and production servers, just configured differently.

We recently changed the server name of our production mail server and went into the scheduled job and changed the command prompt values that run to point to the new server. However, the next morning the job failed and the error log indicated that the job tried to connect to the old mail server.

Is there something I'm missing to updating the SSIS package parameters? Do I have to delete the existing package, and then reimport and reschedule the job again in order for the new server change to hold?

Answer (score 0):

The dba's from where I work had a similar issue. They had to change a job's running parameters, but it seems like running the job with modified parameters only worked the first time they ran it. After that run, it kept using the old values in subsequent runs. They had to repackage the damned thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the package configuration feature? It can be picky on the order of execution.  There's some more info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141132.aspx

Comment: To my knowledge, we use the package configuration during the development phase of the package, but when it actually gets migrated from test to production, the same package is used, but some of the parameters (like database connection string and file paths) are overwritten via the command prompt.